# how long can RDDs be persisted in spark

Tags: apache-spark, persistence, spark-streaming, rdd

I have written a program where I am persisting the RDD inside spark stream so that once new RDD come from spark stream I can join the previously cached RDDs with the new one. Is there a way to set the time to live for this persisted RDDs, so that I can make sure I am not joining the RDDs which I have already got in the last stream cycle.

Also it will be great if someone can explain and point to how once persistance in RDDs work, like when I get the persisted RDDs from spark context how can I join these RDDs across my present RDDs.

Answer (score 1):

In Spark Streaming, the time-to-live of an RDD generated by the Streaming process is controlled by the `spark.cleaner.ttl` configuration. It defaults to infinite but for it to take any effect, we also need to set `spark.streaming.unpersist` to false, in order for Spark streaming to 'let live' the RDDs  generated.

Note that there's no per-RDD ttl possible.